# Импорт данных из JSON с gitlab

Tags: json, reactjs, импорт

Начал изучать reactjs. Мне нужно вытащить данные из файла .json на gitlab. После долгих поисков у меня получился вот такой код:

```
import React from "react";
import MembersData from "./members.json";
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const API = 'https://gitlab.com/Sanguine567/crud-ui/raw/master/members.json';

class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      'items': []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getItems();
  }
  getItems() {
    fetch(proxyurl + API)
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <ul>
      {this.state.items.map(function(item,index) {
        return (
          <div key={index} >
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
      )}
    </ul> 
    );
  }
}
export default Table;
```

Однако данные не выводятся. Ошибка в логе Google Chrome:

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, репозиторий https://gitlab.com/Sanguine567/crud-ui приватный. Поэтому вы получаете в ответе не json, а html с просьбой залогиниться, у которого < первый символ (можете убедиться в вкладке Network в панели разработчика)

Вам надо или сделать этот репозиторий публичным, или залить файл в иное место, или использовать апи гитлаба для доступа к приватному репо https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository

P.S. вероятно апи гитлаба будет работать и без https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Залил файл на публичный репозиторий.  Теперь ошибка: TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function

Comment: @Kirill скорее всего(самого json'a не вижу) в members.json у вас не массив находится, а json начинается с объекта - типо { "members": [] }, а у объекта нет метода .map.
Тогда в стейт вам надо класть в стиле `this.setState({ 'items': results.members})`
А вообще, можете ставить точку останова и посмотреть значения в консоли

Comment: [
        {
        "sammy" : {
        "username" : "SammyShark",
        "location": "Indian Ocean",
        "online" : true,
        "followers" : 987 }
    },
        {
        "jesse" : {
        "username" : "JesseOctopus",
        "location" : "Pacific Ocean",
        "online" : false,
        "followers" : 432 }
    }
]
Это содержимое  json файла. Я никак не могу понять логику обращения к свойствам. К примеру: какой командой мне вывести jesse.location?

Comment: Я пишу:    .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results[0] }));
    <div>{this.state.items.sammy.username}</div>
Получаю ошибку:    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: @Kirill У вас массив, а доступ по ключу работает только у объектов. 
Т.е. json должен быть таким
`{ "sammy": { "username": "SammyShark", "location": "Indian Ocean", "online": true, "followers": 987 }, "jesse": { "username": "JesseOctopus", "location": "Pacific Ocean", "online": false, "followers": 432 } } `, тогда items.jesse.location сработает.

Comment: Или, если оставлять массив, то надо отдельное свойство добавить для ключа, например
`[ { "key": "sammy",  "username" : "SammyShark", "location": "Indian Ocean", "online" : true, "followers" : 987 }, { "key": "jesse", "username" : "JesseOctopus", "location" : "Pacific Ocean", "online" : false, "followers" : 432 } ]` , и искать по нему `items.find(x => x.key == "jesse").location`

Comment: @DmytryDavydov Я привел json  файл к виду без массива, однако теперь получаю ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
Данные выводятся без ошибок, только если я делаю так:
.then(results => this.setState({ items : results.jesse }));
...
{this.state.items.location}

Comment: @Kirill Видимо results.jesse это undefined. Посмотрите(с помощью дебаггера или console.log), что находится в results.jesse